# Joomla Redirect manager not working - 404 error

Tags: redirect, joomla, http-status-code-404

I made a restyling of an old website with Joomla 2.5, and now I need to redirect the old url (not joomla) to the new url.  I have used the Redirect Manager of Joomla but this is not working and I don't know why, I always get the 404 error.

I insert in the Source page:

```
http://www.website.com/site/pippo
```

and the Destination page is:

```
newpage
```

but I've even tried with `http://www.website.com/newpage` and `/newpage`

I have the redirect plugin enabled (and ordered to -1000) and the rewrite is enabled and working correctly.

Comment: Do you have any other 3rd party plugins? is the .htaccess the default Joomla one?

Comment: yes, I don't have any 3rd party plugin, but, now I have "solved" insert all the redirect in the .htaccess and it's only with this solution the redirect work!
Thank you very much!

Comment: how can you order to -1000 ? and why ?
thank you

Answer (score 0):

From what I understand, you are inserting items manually in the redirect component options (backend - Components - Redirect). However, you should be finding the urls automatically inserted there, but disabled.

Click on the ones you wish to redirect, and enter the new url. That works fine both in 2.5 and 3.x.

[image: Redirect screenshot, Joomla! 2.5]

Comment: yes, I've tryed to insert a new one, but nothing. I've made a redirect from the .htaccess, was the only one that work! 
Thank you very much!